# Need a 'for loop' to get dividend data for a stock portfolio, from their respective api urls

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, dictionary

I am trying to automate parsing of dividend data for a stock portfolio, and getting the stock wise dividend values into a single dataframe table.

The data for each stock in a portfolio is stored in a separate api url

The portfolio ids (for stocks - ITC, Britannia, Sanofi) are [500875, 500825, 500674].

I would first like to run a 'for loop' to generate/concatenate each specific url (which goes like this - https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/CorporateAction/w?scripcode=500674), the last 6 digit numbers of urls being their respective company ids

Then I would like to use that url to get each of the respective dividend table's first line into a single dataframe. The code I used to get the individual dividend data, and the final dataframe that I need is represented in image attached

Basically I would like to run a 'for loop' to get the first line of 'Table2' for each stock id and store it in a single data frame as a final result.

[image]

[image]

PS - The code which I used to get individual dividend data is highlighted below:

```
url = 'https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/CorporateAction/w?scripcode=500674'

jsondata = requests.get(url, headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsondata['Table2'])
```

Comment: if you need `for`-loop then use it and show code with this `for`-loop. And you could do all in one `for`-loop. There is no need to create separated `for`-loop to concatenate urls.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `for`-loop then you should use it and show code with `for`-loop and problem which it gives you.

---

You could use single `for`-loop for all works.

You can use string formatting to create url with code and read data from server. Next you can get first row (even without creating `DataFrame`) and append to list with all rows. And after loop you can convert this list to `DataFrame`

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


# --- before loop ---

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

all_rows = []

# --- loop ---

for code in  [500875, 500825, 500674]:

    # use `f-string` of string `.format()` to create url        
    #url = f'https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/CorporateAction/w?scripcode={code}'
    url = 'https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/CorporateAction/w?scripcode={}'.format(code)

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    #print(r.text)  #  to check error message
    #print(r.status_code)

    data = r.json()

    first_row = data['Table2'][0]  # no need to use DataFrame
    #df = pd.DataFrame(data['Table2'])
    #first_row = df.iloc[0]
    #print(first_row)
    
    all_rows.append(first_row)
    
# --- after loop ---

df_result = pd.DataFrame(all_rows)

print(df_result)
```

Result:

```
   scrip_code                  sLongName  ...   Details         PAYMENT_DATE
0      500875                   ITC LTD.  ...   10.1500  2020-09-08T00:00:00
1      500825  BRITANNIA INDUSTRIES LTD.  ...   83.0000  2020-09-16T00:00:00
2      500674           Sanofi India Ltd  ...  106.0000  2020-08-06T00:00:00

[3 rows x 9 columns]
```